# Retrieve Yahoo's User Profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, yahoo-api

This code I have tried this code 
Implementing [Yahoo! Contact Reader Using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/yahoo-contact-reader.aspx) it is working fine but this code is for Read Contact. But I want to code to retrieve users's profile. In user's profile I want to only retrieve user's name, user's email id .

I am confused what should change in the code so that I can get my desired result.

Can anyone help me so that I can get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the profile information by using [guid](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/ysocial_apis-guids.html) and the yql query to get [social profile](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?_uiFocus=social&q=select%20%2a%20from%20social.profile.image%20where%20guid%20in%20%28select%20guid%20from%20social.connections%20where%20owner_guid=me%29;#h=select%20%2a%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20=%20me) `select * from social.profile where guid = me`, you can execute the yql query by passing the query to the url `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=YOUR_QUERY&diagnostics=true` replace the text YOUR_QUERY with the text of your url encoded query

A sample url to execute the yql query `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20%3D%20me&diagnostics=true`